# Issue with OneSignal and Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal service in my Xamarin iOS app, accord the documentation:
https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup

I've made all steps, BUT if i override the AppDelegate methods

```
OnResignActivation
DidEnterBackground
WillEnterForeground
WillTerminate
OnActivated
```

I'm getting the next error:

```
ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException: Cannot get the method descriptor for the selector 'oneSignalApplicationDidBecomeActive:' on the type 'AppDelegate', because the selector does not correspond to a method
```

I need to override those methods, what is my error?

Thanks!

Comment: An issue has been opened for this on github: https://github.com/one-signal/OneSignal-Xamarin-SDK/issues/7 At this time the issue is unresolved - perhaps someone can edit this when the situation changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this in your Application's AppDelegate

```
[Export ("oneSignalApplicationDidBecomeActive:")]
public void OneSignalApplicationDidBecomeActive(UIApplication application) {
    Console.WriteLine ("oneSignalApplicationDidBecomeActive:");
}
```

Comment: There is a detailed update on the [github issue](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Xamarin-SDK/issues/7#issuecomment-281555358) and a [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52660) has been opened.

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue with oneSignalDidFailRegisterForRemoteNotification:error:

Fixed with this code inside AppDelegate. Hope it helps

```
[Export("oneSignalDidFailRegisterForRemoteNotification:error:")]
public void OneSignalDidFailRegisterForRemoteNotification(UIApplication app, NSError error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("oneSignalDidFailRegisterForRemoteNotification:error:");
    }
```